# Include predicted label (phrase) from Microsoft.ML prediction object?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, training-data

I'm wanting to use Microsoft.ML to predict phrases for a handful of categories from a large block of text that isn't consistent in its structure. Because of this, I cannot split up the text block into reliable sections/phrases.

In my database, I have a data set of categorized phrases and large body of text that contains the phrase to train the model from.
I am currently using the LbfgsLogisticRegression trainer to train the model. Is this appropriate or is there a better option?

```
DataTable trainingData = _databaseService.GetDataWithMatchingSurveyName();
List<TrainingModel> sampleData = new List<TrainingModel>();

foreach (DataRow dr in trainingData.Rows)
{
    TrainingModel trainingModel = new TrainingModel
    {
        SurveyName = dr[0].ToString(),
        TextBlock = dr[1].ToString()
    };
    sampleData.Add(trainingModel);
}

List<TrainingModel> trainingData = new List<TrainingModel>();
trainingData.AddRange(sampleData.Select(s => new TrainingModel { Answer = s.SurveyName, Features = new[] { s.TextBlock } }));
MLContext context = new MLContext();
List<IndividualTokenModel> tokenModels = new List<IndividualTokenModel>();

foreach (TrainingModel dataItem in trainingData)
{
    tokenModels.AddRange(dataItem.Features.Select(s => new IndividualTokenModel { Features = s, Label = s.Contains(dataItem.Answer) }));
}
  EstimatorChain<BinaryPredictionTransformer<Microsoft.ML.Calibrators.CalibratedModelParametersBase<Microsoft.ML.Trainers.LinearBinaryModelParameters, Microsoft.ML.Calibrators.PlattCalibrator>>> pipeline = context.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", "Features")
                .AppendCacheCheckpoint(context)
                .Append(context.BinaryClassification.Trainers.LbfgsLogisticRegression());

IDataView dataView = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(tokenModels);
var model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);

PredictionService predictionService = new PredictionService(_trainedModelsDirectory);
context.Model.Save(model, dataView.Schema, predictionService.GetOutputFilePath());
```

The predictions I'm currently getting appear to be fine, based from the probability scores. The prediction only contains the body of text and probability score, so I cannot see the the word/phrase that the prediction was made from. Is it possible to also retrieve the matched (predicted) phrase? Right now, all my predictions are showing the same original text block with scores.

```
MLContext context = new MLContext();
ITransformer trainedModel = context.Model.Load(GetOutputFilePath(), out DataViewSchema _);
PredictionEngine<IndividualTokenModel, PredictionProbabilityModel> predictionEngine = context.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<IndividualTokenModel, PredictionProbabilityModel>(trainedModel);
TrainingModel trainingModel = new TrainingModel { Features = new[] { request.InputValue } };
List<IndividualTokenModel> features = trainingModel.Features.Select(t => new IndividualTokenModel { Features = t }).ToList();

var predictions = features.Select(t => new { Message = t.Features, Prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(t) }).ToList();
foreach (var match in predictions.OrderByDescending(p => p.Prediction.Probability))
{
    if (matches == prediction.QuantityOfPredictions)
    {
        break;
    }
    response.Results.Add(match.Message, match.Prediction.Probability);
    matches++;
}
```

I tried updating my TrainingModel, IndividualTokenModel and PredictionProbabilityModel to include an extra property to output the matched phrase.
I saw on another post that someone added a PredictedLabel column, which I tried implementing, but the value was always null.

I'm hoping to get a prediction that includes the matched phrase for the probability, as well as the current original text block and probability score.